# How do I make this function redirect to a given html page?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a simple script for an exercise I created using Flask, that calculates a tip amount from a meal value entered into a form.

The first function below (meal_total) takes the value entered in the html form and sends it to a second function (tip_calculator) which then processes the tip amount then rendering a new html (tip_amount.html), which displays how much tip must be paid.

The first bit works ok, but when the second function is called, I am not redirected to the new 'tip_amount.html. So how do I get the function to redirect to that html.

```
@app.route('/tip', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def meal_total():
    form = Tip()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        meal = form.meal.data
        tip_calculator(meal)

    else:
        print "please enter your meal amount"
    return render_template('tip.html', 
        form = form)

@app.route('/tip-amount')
def tip_calculator(meal):
    tax = 0.2
    tip = 0.15
    meal_total = meal + meal * tax
    tip = meal_total * 0.15
    return render_template('tip_amount.html',
                           tip = tip)
```

NOTE: I tried using the redirect function as below instead of the render_template(), but it will not allow me to send the parameters (tip) that I need to be displayed int the tip_amount.html template.

```
@app.route('/tip-amount')
def tip_calculator(meal):
    tax = 0.2
    tip = 0.15
    meal_total = meal + meal * tax
    tip = meal_total * 0.15
    return redirect('/tip_amount')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply calling the `tip_calculator()` function without returning its response:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    meal = form.meal.data
    tip_calculator(meal)
```

Add a `return` there:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    meal = form.meal.data
    return tip_calculator(meal)
```

`tip_calculator` is merely a support function here; you don't need to register it as a route at all.

You can use redirection still, but then you'd usually pass along any parameters as query parameters in the URL; this is easily done with `url_for()`, any extra parameters are rendered as URL parameters:

```
from flask import url_for

if form.validate_on_submit():
    meal = form.meal.data
    return redirect(url_for('tip_calculator', meal=meal))
```

which'll redirect you to `/tip-amount?meal=<meal>` (with the meal value filled in).

Your `tip_calculator` route would then take that value from the request:

```
@app.route('/tip-amount')
def tip_calculator():
    meal = request.args.get('meal', type=int)
    if meal is None:
        # redirect back to form if the parameter is missing or not an integer
        return redirect(url_for('meal_total'))
    tax = 0.2
    tip = 0.15
    meal_total = meal + meal * tax
    tip = meal_total * 0.15
    return render_template('tip_amount.html', tip=tip)
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn! However, when I try your solution using url_for and passing the meal value as a URL parameter, I get an error: `raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('tip_calculator', {'meal': 300}, None)` @Martijn Pieters

Comment: That means there is no `tip_calculator` endpoint then or your version of that view has a route with parameters that are too strict. Make sure you have a `tip_calculator` function registered just as I show in my answer.

Comment: Ok great I'll look into that. In your opinion, is there an advantage to using the url_for method and passing the value as a URL parameter, rather than calling the returning the function directly and passing through the variable as a parameter of the function? Or in what use cases would you use one over the other?

Comment: It depends on what this should look like to the site visitor; a redirect gives them a new URL in the location bar. Reloading the page is then a different experience, as is the history of their browser session (using the back button). This can be important for POST forms too; without a redirect reloading would apply the same 'change' again, after a redirect your only reload the result page, not re-apply the change.